# Adding a new organization in a running network deployed on different hosts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running a network of 3 organizations, each running in it's own AWS instance. I deployed the network using a 3 organizations version of Altoros' Ansible Fabric Starter with Raft ordering (https://github.com/Altoros/Ansible-Fabric-Starter). Now I would like to extend it, while it runs, by adding a fourth organization on a fourth host. How can it be done?

I've already found the tutorial in HF's documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html) and a similar one in Medium (https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2) for a network running in the same host. I've also managed to some extent to adapt it to my multi-host network, but I encounter the following error when running `peer channel join -b mychannel.block` from the cli of the new organization (org3):

```
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied: channel [] creator org [org3MSP])
```

And the logs of the orderer of org0 show:

```
[protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 085 channel []: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 086 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.3:35236 error="access denied: channel [] creator org [org3MSP]" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=970.013µs
```

**I also find it quite difficult (at least not straight forward) to add a new organization, even in a single host network, and it got me wondering if I had not missed something (because I would expect the addition of a new organization to be something quite useful and common in a lot of use cases, and I was therefore surprised by the complexity of the task).**

Comment: Was your configuration block update successful?
If yes, check once by fetching config block and make sure that 4th org is part of channel

Comment: Thank you for your comment @PAVAN. The update was indeed successful, and I confirm that the 4th org is now part of the channel, as it appears in the last config block just as the three other orgs do. The only noticeable difference is the 4th org doesn't have an anchor peer defined in the config block(whereas other orgs do), but I believe it shouldn't have any effect on our matter.

Comment: In the config block there should be a section that looks like this:
`
"config": {
  "admins": ["<certificate>"],
  "crypto_config": {
    "identity_identifier_hash_function": "SHA256",
     "signature_hash_family": "SHA2"
  },
  "name": "Org1MSP",
  "root_certs": ["<certificate>"],
  "tls_root_certs": ["<certificate>"]
}
`
for your organisation. Try to decode the <certificates> with printf <certificate> | base64 -D and compare them with what you are using as Org3 crypto material.